# How to add new role in chamilo 1.11.6? For example current we have HR, Learner, trainer, etc. How to set permissions for the role?

Tags: chamilo-lms

I am trying to add new role to chamilo 1.11.6. I want to set permissions to that role. For ex. I want to add new role Head of Department. How to add rights to that role.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chamilo 1.* does not have a feature to create new roles from the interface. If you want to do that, you will have to do some (PHP) programming.

This is, for several reasons, one of the features that Chamilo does *not* provide, and the reason why you already have about 14 different roles (look at roles constants definitions in main/inc/lib/api.lib.php) predefined with the basic software.

Chamilo 2.0 (the roadmap plans for a first release this year) will offer the underlying elements to enable granular roles and permissions definitions, but it will not directly offer the feature to final users and is not ready for production use yet.

I would recommend you check the definitions of roles in the admin guide (https://docs.chamilo.org/) and try to find something that roughly fits what you need.

Obviously, you could also pick another LMS software that offers granular roles and permissions management, but you would probably loose the ease of use which is Chamilo's main advantage.

-edit-

You can assign only about 5 roles when creating a new user. Other roles are cumulative and can be added only in context: inside courses or sessions (course assistant is for users inside the users list inside a course, session general coach is the teacher you assign as general coach when creating a session, ...).

The anonymous role is a role assigned to users when they *do not* have a user account.

Comment: Thanks. There are 14 different roles in api.lib.php. How to assign those roles to users. Admin only allows to assign few of that 14 roles to users, like learner, trainer, HR, Session admin and student superior. Can you help me on that.
Thank you